# How to generate report logs in cucumber-selenium framework

Tags: selenium, cucumber-junit

I have use the below code in my testrunner to generate html report in cucumber-selenium framework.

```
package selenium_cucumber_project_pkg;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @Cucumber.Options(
               features="features",
               glue= {"stepdefinition"},
               format={"pretty", "html:report/cucumber-html-report"}  
              )

public class testrunner {

}
```

But i have to save each files in the report directory.So how can i create unique report files by concatenating current date&time with the file name.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of cucumber you are using?

Comment: I am using cucumber-jvm.version=1.1.2

Comment: That is like 5 years old. Any specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a runtime shutdown hook in the `BeforeClass` or `AfterClass` of the runner.

```
@AfterClass
    public static void after() {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
        {
              public void run()
              {         
                try {
                    Files.move(Paths.get("report"), Paths.get("report - "+ 
                LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("L-d-YYYY H-m-s"))), 
                            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            });
    }
```